# Returning directory string to a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to get my FolderBrowserDialog to show it's selected path in a textblock using WPF. I learned that you can create a new function in C# using the `Click=""` in XAML but the `x:Name=""` doesn't link a new event handler like the click did. So how do I get my string to return to the textblock?

XAML TextBox:

```
<TextBlock Text="Input Directory" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 10" />
<TextBox x:Name="InputDirectoryBox" IsReadOnly="True" Padding="2" />
```

C# code:

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    private void InputButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(fbd.SelectedPath);
            foreach (string directory in files)
                MessageBox.Show(directory);
        }
    }
```

Also is there a way to use the GetDirectories property without using an array? Like a singular directory?

Comment: `x:Name` gives name to your control (here is textbox) so you can reference to that control with that name. I don't know how is that related to Click event? I didn't understand your question

Comment: so I gave my textbox a name of "InputDirectoryBox". But it does not automatically throw it into the c# script like Click did. I am still very new to c# and wpf so I do not know how they call each other and interact. Would "InputDirectoryBox" work similarily to a class or a variable? How would I refer to it within my code?

Also, how would I change the GetDirectories property without using an array? I would only like to allow a single directory to go into my textbox!

Comment: Assign a name to your `TextBox` and the use it like this : `InputDirectoryBox.Text = files[0];`

Comment: There are literally thousands of question on Stack Overflow discussing how to set control properties like `Text`, both inadequate and adequate. See marked duplicate for example of the latter, which explains how to set up a property for binding, using `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Even better if you search for "MVVM" and apply that technique to a regular view model instead of the window class itself. Of course, you can also give the element a name via `x:Name` and then reference the generated field in your code-behind, but that's the wrong way to use WPF.

Comment: as for this: _"how would I change the GetDirectories property without using an array?"_ -- first, that's a whole other question, and should be posted as one. Second, you need to explain your question better. Given the call to `GetDirectories()` necessarily can always return two or more elements in the array, what _"single directory"_ is it that you expect to display in the textbox? Be specific, stating clearly _exactly_ the behavior you want.

Comment: Peter, while I get where your coming from, I did actually use many searches but the information I was seeking was not clear to me since I'm interpreting it through my own project. Programmings hard, especially if your new. It would be nice if you didn't invalidate my question. Thank you anyway though, I did manage to figure it out